# n1ql.delete not working in spring data couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring data couchbase and I want to write a custom query for deleting all the docs based on some condition
I have below query written down:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.delete} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND " +
     "accountId = $1 #{#n1ql.returning}")
  Mono<Void> delete(String accountId);
```

But this does not seem to be working. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?
Please show the calling code and how you determine it does not work.
Two things to check-
If the document to be deleted was just inserted, it may not yet have been indexed.
This is a  reactive repository - tbe n1ql wiil not be executed unless the result is collected.